# slueth with rxjava2 creating multiple traces

Tags: spring-cloud, zipkin, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am using spring cloud slueth with zipkin in spring boot to trace the services calls.

My spring cloud version is Edgware.RELEASE

Now I when I tried to trace my facade layer which uses rxjava, it creates 12 traces for a single request?

What should I do ? I mean i want just 1 trace should be generated for 1 request of facade layer(facade layer do parallel calls using rxjava).

I am using slueth with http and have not change any property if properties file

I have added these 2 dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

This I have added in properties file:

```
spring.zipkin.baseUrl: http://172.16.3.197:9411/
spring.slueth.enabled: true
spring.sleuth.sampler.percentage: 1
```